# Sorting a Binary Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, tree

I have written a simple binary tree using structures and a couple of functions in order to add, search, find the minimum and maximum values, remove a node as well as destroy the node, the problem is that I have been using recursion and dealing with it in the same way and I am having a hard time trying to comprehend if my function for sorting the algorithm is efficient enough.

The whole code is:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

/*
  This is a very simple example demonstrating a very basic binary tree to be
  implemented using structurs, later on I would like to create this by using
  classes, but for now, structures and pointers would suffice
*/


/*
 * The node is created in here, notice how the pointer has the ability to
 * self reference to 2 different positions, this means that there is the ability
 * to store to 2 different branches of memory
 *
 */

struct node{
  int key_value;
  node * p_left;
  node * p_right;
};

/*
 *
 * This is the creation of the add function that will add to the linked list
 *
 */

node* add(node * p_tree, int key) {
  //--The base case of the recursive function will be placed in here
  //--since binary trees are recursive in nature and linked data structures
  //--are as a whole in terms of space and memory, the recursive function will
  //--suffice for most cases involving binary trees.
  //--In this case, if the given parameter is null, we create the tree
  //--by allocating the necessary memory space
  if (p_tree == NULL) {
    node * pnew_tree = new node;
    pnew_tree->p_left = NULL;
    pnew_tree->p_right = NULL;
    pnew_tree->key_value = key;
    return pnew_tree;
  }// end of base case

  //--Depending of the value of the node, we determine if we will add to the left side or the right side of the subtree
  if (key < p_tree->key_value){
    // if it is less than the value, we add to the left
    p_tree->p_left = add(p_tree->p_left, key);
  }
  else{
    p_tree->p_right = add(p_tree->p_right, key);
  }
  return p_tree;
} // end of function


/*
 *
 * This is where the search function will be created
 * in here the function will go over all the subtrees untill the one with the necessary key is returned
 * again, this uses recursive functions doing things step by step:
 *
 * First: Look to see if the given tree node is empty(NULL) if yes then return NULL
 *
 * Second: If we find the key by referencing the key value, then we are done and return that particular tree
 *
 * Third: Otherwise, look into the left and right sides of the tree making recursive calls to this very same function until
 *        the one that we are looking for is found.
 *
 */

node* search(node *p_tree, int key) {
  //--First:
  if (p_tree == NULL) { return NULL; }

  //--Second:
  else if (p_tree->key_value == key) { return p_tree; }

  //--Third:
  else if(key < p_tree->key_value) {
    search(p_tree->p_left, key); //--Thus it looks into the left with the same recursive algorithm
  }
  else {
    search(p_tree->p_right, key);
  }
}//--End of recursive search function

/*
 *
 * Easiest function to implement, since the delete key is used being that the whole concept falls inside memory being allocated to the
 * list via the creation of new nodes(this means using the new keyword to allocate memory, much like creating new objects in other languages)
 *
 * First: Check to see if passed tree is not null, if not null destroy the left and right subtree using the same function
 *        else nothing.
 *
 * NOTE: The return value is set to void since it returns nothing back to the list
 *
 */
void destroy_node(node* p_tree) {
  //--First
  if (p_tree != NULL) {
    destroy_node(p_tree->p_left);
    destroy_node(p_tree->p_right);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Destroying left subtree node" << endl;
    cout << "Destroying right subtree node" << endl;
    cout << "Deleting the entire node: " << p_tree->key_value << endl;
    cout << endl;
    delete p_tree;
  }
}//--End of recursive destroy function



/*
 *
 * Finding the max value is simple, we evaluate the left and right node and use base cases to see which node to return
 * Why just right?
 * looking back at the theory behind binary trees, the tree on the right is always the biggest element. That is how trees are normally sorted.
 * there is no need to look at the keys, the code will sort out by itself in this space since if it is not null it will return the highest.
 */
node* return_max(node* p_tree) {
  if (p_tree == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  if (p_tree->p_right == NULL) {
    return p_tree;
  }
  return return_max(p_tree->p_right);
} //--End of return max recursive function


/*
 *
 * Max node, basically the opposite of the avobe taking advantage of the fact that the left node is lesser
 * recursion will be used again
 *
 */

node* return_min(node* p_tree){
  if (p_tree == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  if(p_tree->p_left == NULL) {
    return p_tree;
  }
  return return_min(p_tree->p_left);
}//--End of recursive return min function

/*
 *
 * We need a remove max function in order to properly remove the biggest node in case it is found, that way we can implement a recursive
 * algorithm inside the  function in charge of removing the node we want, we can simply remove the node by using delete or destroy once we
 * find it because that would only destroy the entire tree! No no, that is not good.
 *
 */
node* remove_max_node(node* p_tree, node* p_max_node) {
  if (p_tree == NULL) { return NULL;}

  if (p_tree == p_max_node) {
    return p_max_node->p_left; //--Because the left one is lesser
  }
  //--Now for the recursive call, implementing this means that we will remove from the node on the right
  //--basing us on the sense that the right tree is the highest one, it will go then from top to bottom
  p_tree->p_right = remove_max_node(p_tree->p_right, p_max_node);
  //--return the tree after the changes in the addresses have been conducted properly
  return p_tree;

}




/*
 *
 *
 *
 *
 * Removing from a tree is also simple based on the recursive nature of the element being discussed
 *
 * First: Check to see if the tree is null, if yess, return null
 *
 */
node* removeN(node* p_tree, int key) {
  //--First:
  if (p_tree == NULL) { return NULL;}
  //--Second
  if(p_tree->key_value == key) {
    //--Third:
    if (p_tree->p_left == NULL) {
      node* p_right_sub = p_tree->p_right;
      delete p_tree;
      return p_right_sub;
    }
    if (p_tree->p_right == NULL) {
      node* p_left_sub = p_tree->p_left;
      delete p_tree;
      return p_left_sub;
    }

    node* p_maxN = return_max(p_tree->p_left);
    p_maxN->p_left = remove_max_node(p_tree->p_left, p_maxN);
    p_maxN->p_right = p_tree->p_right;
    delete p_tree;
    return p_maxN;
  }
  else if(key < p_tree->key_value) {
    p_tree->p_left = removeN(p_tree->p_left, key);
  }
  else {
    p_tree->p_right = removeN(p_tree->p_right, key);
  }
  //--After all  changes have been done
  return p_tree;
}

/*
 *
 * The entire implementation is sorted when calling return min and max
 *
 *
 */
 node* sortedN(node* p_tree){
  if (p_tree == NULL){return NULL;}

  return sortedN(return_max(p_tree));
 }





int main(int argv, char* []){

  cout << "This is merely a test" << endl;
  node myBinaryTree = {1};

  add(&myBinaryTree, 2);

  if(search(&myBinaryTree,2)) {cout << "Node found" << endl;}
  return 0;
}
```

My understanding is that the way I defined the other functions originally already sort and return the state of the node itself in a new way being that I am using pointers. Maybe I am wrong to think that my sorting function works. I have been with this all day and cannot think of a better way, most of my code was written for the understanding I have in it and the help of my books, my instructor is not being much help as well so I came here seeking some wisdom. (Originally posted in stack overflow but moved over here due to it working properly and only asking for a review and better implementation of the last algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

## Bugs

In this line of your search function (*in a [previous version of the post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/106080/2), before the fix*):

> ```
> else if (p_tree->key_value = key) { return p_tree; }
> ```

you used `=` when you meant to use `==`.  You should always turn on full compiler warnings to help find errors like this.

In this line of the same function:

> ```
> search(p_tree->p_left, key);
> ```

you forgot to use `return` as in:

```
 return search(p_tree->p_left, key);
```

Again, compiler warnings would have alerted you to this error.

## Infinite recursion

I'm not sure what `sortedN()` is supposed to do since your binary tree is already sorted.  But what it actually does is recurse infinitely.

Comment: ah thank you, the bug had been corrected. I had thought the same regarding the sortedN() function, I already had in my head that the algorithm was already sorted in the proper way by the implementation of the additional nodes being added to the list, I just was not sure enough about it. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.